# Trigger to Add Newly Inserted Rows in Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, triggers

I am working on developing a triggerr in oracle SQL developer that would copy every newly inserted row in a specific table X to another table Y. The number of attributes in both X and Y tables do not match. That's why I am just taking a subset of the attributes in table X and filling in table Y
Here is the code I worked out but it is not working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ESURUSAGE
AFTER INSERT
ON X
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
  user_ID   Varchar(10);
BEGIN 
  Select user_name INTO user_ID
    From X A
    Where A.user_name = :new.user_name;
  INSERT INTO Y 
  ('DSS', SYSDATE, upper(user_ID) , null , null, upper(user_ID), upper(user_ID), SYSDATE, SYSDATE); 
END;
```

Comment: There is no value between two commas: `upper(user_ID), , upper(user_ID)`, this causes a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure about the `MySQL` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to select user_name from table X since you already have this information. You also have a spare "," in your insert statement. Try something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ESURUSAGE
AFTER INSERT
ON X
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO Y VALUES
  ('DSS', SYSDATE, upper(:new.user_name) , null , null, upper(:new.user_name), upper(:new.user_name), SYSDATE, SYSDATE); 
END;
```

Comment: now it's giving me this error:
Error(3,4): PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: You have missed a `VALUES` keyword in the insert query. `INSERT INTO Y VALUES (`.

Comment: @Dba this time it's giving me different error i.e.:
Error(2,15): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
it does not make sense because X and Y both exist and I can do select * from both of them!

Comment: @shaklasah, Check that the table `X` exists in user_tables view. `SELECT * FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'X;`

Comment: @Dba no it does not! should this mean that I can't insert in table  Y if it is not owned by the same owner as of X. Or if it does not lie in the same data scope/schema

Comment: @shaklasah, So it might be a synonym. the user may not have sufficient privilege to insert on that table.